# New laptop's SSD SMART reported about 1.4TBs of total read and 1.4TBs of total write and 6 hrs of power on time

Tags: laptop, ssd, smart, m.2

It's a 512GB m.2 drive.

Is this normal somehow?

Definitely not normal for my limited experiences with the newly purchased SSDs and computers.

For about 1.4TBs of total read and write and 6 hours of power on time, it looks like it was running read and write stress tests for those 6 hours.
Why though?
I can't recall any other new computers and ssds had smart logs looked like this.

Laptop's packaging was sealed and intact, so I don't think it was tampered.

Comment: Could be a factory test. Would not worry.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Even a bloated OEM version of installation is way less than 1TB, even if doubled or tripled.

Comment: I'd not be too surprised that if a vendor simply reseal it after the replacement of a component in a return. Sometimes it could be a return that has nothing broken as well. Some retailers have tricks to make it look sealed as well. IMO it really depends on where you are and/or where the brand is.

Comment: From what I can recall, after a win 10/11 installation, new SSDs typically logged 20~30GBs of total write which are basically matching the OSs' sizes on the disk, and afterwards I will manually do some system settings then auto updates. No way in normal setup scenarios 
the disk will have 1.4TBs write in 6hrs .

Comment: And I don't think vendors need to write 1.4TBs of data after some component replacement. Even it's a used disk no way in normal using scenario it will have 1.4TBs of write in 6 hrs, and I have to add it's a 512GB m.2. This is really abnormal.

Comment: The factory test @Giacomo1968 mentioned, the most logical explanation BTW, is in no way dependent on the OS installation and has no correlation with the data used in its installation. As a matter of fact, OSes in mass produced PCs aren't installed like you and I would do at home or, sometimes, at work. It's a source image copied to multiple drives at once.

Comment: What @TomYan describes could be correct as well. Nowadays there are more kinds of “sketchy” refurbished items being sold by folks who are selling used items as “lightly used” which is deceptive. This could be a floor model of an item that might have been never “used” so repackaged as “refurbished.” If you are truly concerned, please just return the item to whoever you purchased it from for a full refund. If this is just an issue with the M.2 drive, just return the drive. But if you feel unsure about hardware purchased as “new” just return it for your own basic peace of mind.

Comment: Btw, it could also be the SMART data being interpreted in a wrong way by the software you use. SMART data has never really been standardized so even different model from the same vendor can have very different data spec. And I seem to have misread "factory test" as "factory reset". My bad. But again, just like you might be able to return it now, obviously another buyer might have performed their own "factory test" and be able to return it, and I doubt that that means the next buyer always gets a new drive or must be buying it as "refurbished", unless you country has some strict law on that.

Comment: Brand model of the SSD. There's some Samsungs doing this, might be some firmware issue. See https://www.techpowerup.com/303984/samsung-990-pro-flagship-ssd-has-an-endurance-problem-users-notice-rapid-drive-health-drops but there's other models too.

Comment: Post SMART data